# Is it possible to create a shortcut that opens windows cmd in specific folder?

Tags: windows, cmd

Is it possible to create a desktop shortcut or task bar shortcut that opens a CMD window in a specified directory on a windows OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible and easy, without creating anything else than a shortcut:

1. create a shortcut of cmd.exe (command prompt) on your  (drag'n'drop the icon to your desktop)
2. edit its properties and change `start in` to the required directory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, tricky one is like. Create .bat file with cd $folderPath and open folder to $folderPath

Answer (score 0):

ConEmu is quite a useful tool (and free) as it allows you to start a command window within a folder by simply right clicking in the folder and selecting from the menu.

If you have only one specific folder, though, and you want to create a shortcut for it, set your shortcut to...

cmd /K "cd C:[YourFolderName]\"

Substituting as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to cmd.exe.  Right click on the shortcut and select properties.  At the end of the Target add /k and the command to navagate to the directory in double quotes.  For example, this takes you to the root directory:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k "cd\"
```